# Return type as IEnumerable instead of just List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I am doing a .NET MVC tutorial. With that being said, I've came across code like this:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var movies = GetMovies();

        return View(movies);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
    {
        return new List<Movie>
        {
            new Movie {Id = 1, Name = "Shrek"},
            new Movie {Id = 2, Name = "LotR"}
        };
    }
}
```

Index view for Movies looks like:

```
@model IEnumerable<VideoStore.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movies</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Movie</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var movie in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@movie.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So my question is, why in the `MoviesController` in the private method `GetMovies()`, the `IEnumerable` return type is used? Why not to use the `List` return type?

Comment: That way you can change it to return an array or anything that implements IEnumerable and you will not have to change the code that uses it.  Basically you just expose the least derived type that has alll the functionality that is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Return type as IEnumerable instead of just List?

```
//controller

var a = new Dictionary<string, string>();
return View(a);

var b = new List<string>();
return View(b);

var c = new LinkedList<string>();
return View(c);

// All work with:

@model IEnumerable<string>
```

While using an `IEnumerable<>` is more *Open* [sOlid Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), I rarely recommend passing any collection type interface/class to a view.

While in C# arrays/collections are [First-Class Citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) the issue is that they are not extensible while maintaining the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

For example:

```
// Controller Returns:
var people = .... as IEnumerable<Person>;
return View(people);

@model IEnumerable<Person>
```

Now suppose to want to add any information to the view that has nothing to do with the group (like a title to the page).. how do you do that?  You could extend and make your own class that derives from `IEnumerable<T>` but that breaks the SRP because the Title of the page has nothing to do with the group of people.  Instead you should create a First-Class Model that represents everything the view needs:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public string Title { get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set;}
}

return View(myViewModel);

@model MyViewModel
```

I suggest *always* doing this.  As soon as you start using partials or templates in MVC, or want to post back the same object, it becomes increasingly difficult to move away from `IEnumerable<>` because you need to changes Partials and/or Templates and/or Javascript...

> So my question is, why in the `MoviesController` in the private method `GetMovies()`, the `IEnumerable<>` return type is used?

Generally it's good practice to [Program against an Interface and not an Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), also referred to as [Design by contract (DbC), also known as contract programming, programming by contract and design-by-contract programming,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

It's a [soLid Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) specifically Liskov substitution principle.  Excerpt:

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming stating that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e. an object of type T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering any of the desirable properties of the program (correctness, task performed, etc.). More formally, the Liskov substitution principle (LSP) is a particular definition of a subtyping relation, called (strong) behavioral subtyping, that was initially introduced by Barbara Liskov in a 1987 conference keynote address titled Data abstraction and hierarchy. It is a semantic rather than merely syntactic relation, because it intends to guarantee semantic interoperability of types in a hierarchy, object types in particular. Barbara Liskov and Jeannette Wing described the principle succinctly in a 1994 paper as follows...

In practice it means the current code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var movies = GetMovies();

        return View(movies);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
    {
        return new List<Movie>
        {
            new Movie {Id = 1, Name = "Shrek"},
            new Movie {Id = 2, Name = "LotR"}
        };
    }
```

Could change to:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMovieDb _movieDb;
    // Dependency Injecting access to movies
    public MoviesController(IMovieDb movieDb)
    {
        _movieDb = movieDb;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var movies = _movieDb .GetMovies();

        return View(movies);
    }
    // ....


public interface IMovieDb
{
    IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies();
}
```

Now we have no idea how the Movies are retrieved... and we shouldn't care as long as the contract/interface fulfills our data needs.

Comment: Wow, a lot of efforts spent on this answer. In your last example, you injected `movieDb`, but then used `iocDA`. Typo?

Comment: That's a lot of information @Erik, thank you so much for your effort! I will definitely go back again to your answer later on as great source of knowledge. For now, your answer & Racil answer made huge clarification of this subject!

Answer (score 3):

`IEnumerable<>` is the interface relevant to iterating over a `List<>`.  Returning a `List<>` would immediately expose more operations to the consumer of `GetMovies()` than is strictly necessary--such as adding or removing from the collection--which could make it easier to introduce errors.  There is no technical reason to choose `IEnumerable<>` over `List<>`, because under the hood it will behave the same.  The decision is purely practical.

Answer (score 3):

Using IEnumerable weakens the coupling, which allows it to be forward compatible with other concrete types should the implementation change. All of the following changes could be made without changing the interface:

```
//Original
private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
{
    return new List<Movie>
    {
        new Movie {Id = 1, Name = "Shrek"},
        new Movie {Id = 2, Name = "LotR"}
    };
}

//Using an array
private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
{
    return new Movie[]
    {
        new Movie {Id = 1, Name = "Shrek"},
        new Movie {Id = 2, Name = "LotR"}
    };
}

//From EF
private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
{
    return dbContext.Movies.Where( m => Name == "Shrek" || Name == "Lotr );
}


//Covariant
class NerdMovie : Movie {}

private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
{
    return new List<NerdMovie>
    {
        new NerdMovie {Id = 1, Name = "Shrek"},
        new NerdMovie {Id = 2, Name = "LotR"}
    };
}


//Custom type
class MovieList : List<Movie> { }

private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
{
    return new MovieList
    {
        new Movie {Id = 1, Name = "Shrek"},
        new Movie {Id = 2, Name = "LotR"}
    };
}

//Using yield
private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
{
    yield return new Movie {Id = 1, Name = "Shrek"};
    yield return new Movie {Id = 2, Name = "LotR"};
}
```

Comment: That's only correct on the receiving side (i.e. the view), not the giving side (i.e. the `GetMovies` function). You can return `List` from the function to the view that's expecting `IEnumerable` and still have the exact same decoupling. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I disagree; it is not the exact same decoupling. By exposing a List in the method definition, the service is committing to providing a List, which can be significant, e.g. if the method is part of an interface or contract and there is a requirement for forward compatibility.  It is sometimes wise to make only the commitments you need to and nothing more. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I explained in my answer. But for the code in the question, none of those conditions is applicable. The class is not implementing an interface, and the function is returning a list. In that specific case, there is absolutely no benefit for using the interface as a return type and it will not change the coupling/decoupling in any way.

Comment: I think we agree on how the language works. The confusing thing for me is the way you are discussing coupling with regards to the "code in question." Coupling is a concept that extends beyond the code in question, since it has to do with whether changes in one thing require changes in another. In my answer I show a half dozen ways to change the method that would require you to change the calling code too if you used the concrete type. So it's incorrect to say there is a no difference in the coupling.

Comment: Read the question carefully. The OP is not asking about the calling code (i.e. the view). The type is defined there as `IEnumerable`, so it will accept all those methods in your answer. The OP asked about the returned type from the `GetMovies` function. And I was saying that in the specific code in the question, changing the return type from `IEnumerable` to `List` will not impact the coupling in any way. The view is still accepting `IEnumerable` and all your functions will work with it. The only time the function return type makes a difference is if the function is implementing an interface.

Comment: When you write "will not impact the coupling in any way" I think you mean "will not affect the logic of the existing code in any way." And I agree with that statement. The coupling itself is definitely changed; it would become more tightly coupled.

Comment: OK, so  you're looking at it from a more generic sense, and we completely agree with each other on that level. But when it comes to the code in the question, how is changing the return type of the function makes it more coupled with the view which still expects `IEnumerable`? Nothing changed there and you can still switch it with any function from your answer. Show me a case where the function works with `IEnumerable` and stops working with `List` and then I will agree that it is more coupled, but such a case doesn't exist for this specific code.

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is that although using a more generic type is an important part in decoupling, it is not enough by itself alone in this code to change the coupling. You will also need to either make the function & class implement an interface like I mentioned in my answer, or you'll need to use injection like in Erik's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak to the exact reasoning of the developer behind a specific code, but in general we use the most generic acceptable type (usually an interface) for input, like done in the view. This allows us to get data from different resources and switch between them.

As for returning output, there is no benefit in returning the generic interface instead of the actual type unless the function returns different subtypes depending on some conditions, which is not the case in your example. Alternatively, if the class itself is implementing an interface then it is useful for the interface to return the most generic acceptable type for the same reason above. This is also not your case, so in your case, returning the `IEnumerable` has no benefit.

Comment: Wow, thank you Racil for this and other answers in my question. You gave me a nice piece of knowledge here! Btw, so using IEnumerable doesn't speed up app, does it (I was thinking maybe it was the reason)?

Comment: No, even though the return type is `IEnumerable<>`, the code is still returning a `List<>`.  The only difference is that the consumer can only see the methods exposed by `IEnumerable<>` until it is casted to another type.

Comment: Not for returning it, no. In the view, looping through `IEnumerable` could be a bit different (faster or slower) depending on how it is done. But returning `List` instead of `IEnumerable` will not affect the performance in any measurable way.

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable is interface so it is more flexible , if you use List , you are forcing the receiving method to expect List.

Comment: Thanks, I give you +, but Luke Samuel answer is more complex, so I will mark his answer.

Comment: That's incorrect. You can perfectly return a `List` to the view that is expecting an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks @RacilHilan for claryfication.

Comment: @RacilHilan: how about method that is expecting Array ?

Comment: I don't get your question. What about it? Comments are not a good place for asking and answering questions. You can post a question with code if you want us to give you good answers. Or at least explain what you mean by a method expecting an array.